# Symfony Twig - get default _locale in twig

Tags: symfony, path, twig, translation, locale

I'm adding a language switcher on my website.

my parameters are like this :

```
avc_coming_soon:
resource: "@AVCComingSoonBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /{_locale}
defaults:
    _locale: en
requirements:
    _locale: |fr
```

`en` is set by default

In my twig, I did that:

```
<div class="languages">
        <ul class="lang-menu">
            <li class="en"><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), {'_locale': 'en' })  }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/flag_en.gif') }}" alt="EN"></a></li>
            <li class="fr"><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), {'_locale': 'fr'})  }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/flag_fr.gif') }}" alt="FR"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But when I click on 'English', my path become `www.mysite.com/en` or the good route is `www.mysite.com/` (without the `/en`) because in parameters, I have this :

```
defaults:
    _locale: en
```

How to get the default _locale in twig ?

```
{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), {'_locale': <<<default>>> })  }}
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `app.request.attributes`:

```
{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), {'_locale': app.request.attributes.get('_locale') })  }}
```

If you have configuration in controller you need to set default value in function parameter:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="coming_soon", options={"expose"=true}, requirements={"_locale" = "fr|en"})
 */
public function indexAction($_locale = 'en')
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: doesn't work because if i'm on 'www.mysite.com/fr' and then I click on 'English', the path become 'www.mysite.com/fr' and not 'www.mysite.com/'. And/Or if I'm on 'www.mysite.com/' and then I click on 'English', the path become 'www.mysite.com//'

Comment: It is another problem.

Comment: Why have you been redirected to `mysite.com/fr` when you request `mysite.com/`? Do you have redirect rules for that?

Comment: No, when I request `mysite.com/`, the website is in English and when I request `mysite.com/fr`, the website is in French. What I need is when I'm on `mysite.com/fr` and I'm clicking on 'English, the request must be `mysite.com/` and not `mysite.com/en` . In my controller I did that : `* @Route("/", name="coming_soon", options={"expose"=true}, requirements={"_locale" = "fr|en"})`

Comment: It is another question than you asked. But I updated my answer to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

I use this bundle: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Thanks to the bundle I never have to mess with locales..

You can configure the bundle to prefix everything except the default locale (which is what you wan't, reading the comments to the other answer).

And for the language switcher you simply set the **_locale** on any given route.

Answer (score 0):

when using '%locale%' parameter from service.yaml the value in twig file does not change using subscriber. Using this code works for me:

```
app.request.session.get('_locale')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.